# Android and Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Where can I find a working code synchronization app file Android and Google Drive? Personally, I have not found. A software code provided by Google "for example" are not working. Not a video from google, not after correcting bugs.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start with Android quickstart: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android
- There is also a sample Android app: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android
- For synchronizing data with appdata folder, here is another sample: https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android

Try these and whenever you are stuck, post exact error to get is resolved.